# Supply Source for <div>

Tags: jquery, html, textboxlist

is it possible to Supply a External HTML for `<div>` tag?

I have tried `.load()` in jquery but It bugs the `textboxlist`, and I tried using `ajax` too but it has the same effect with the `textboxlist`. is there anyway to supply the source for `<div>` in html like `iframe`?

example:

`<div src="existing.php"></div>`

I found something like this, they said this works but for me it does not. so any suggestion?

Comment: $.load() should be working, what issues were you facing?

Comment: yes you can using the method load are could you show us if you are getting are error and also what are you using for the server side?

Comment: You should think long and hard about why you want to do this. What content are you trying to load that you can't simply include within the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, why not something like this?

```
<div id="externalHTML">
   <?php include_once('existing.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Or should this page be loaded dynamically on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your jQuery selection is returning more than one element( the diva and some other elements in your form) and it updates everything.

Give a **unique id** to your div and you will be able to use load function without any probelms.

**HTML**

```
<div id="divExisting"></div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){
  $("#divExisting").load("existing.php");
});
```

The above function will make sure that the `load` function will be executed only after the dom loaded completely.

Comment: +1 not for the unique which I don't thing is the issue, it's probably because his selector doesn't wait for the DOM ready.

Comment: @gdoron : Thanks. Mentioned about Unique Id because OP was saying, using ajax messed up other elements. so i guessed the selectore returned more than one. I will update the answer to include why we need dom ready.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an iFrame:

```
<iframe src="existing.php"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text box list is very similar to jQuery Mobile. It has to components, one is the input and the other one is another display box like: div or ul (unordered list) or something similar. So what you need to do is either edit the input type text field or the unordered list html content and then use either getValues() or setValues() method and most likely folowed by the update() method. For API documentation check this link: http://www.devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/